ROS2 Humble Navigation Stack randomly gets stuck receiving goal position
currently I am setting up a container environment with Apptainer for our mobile robots.
Inside the container Gazebo with ROS2 Humble will be launch.
For testing only I setup a simple application that starts up Gazebo and the navigation stack and then automatically sends a goal through the /navigate_to_pose action server.
In 95% of the cases this works fine and a path is planned.
But in 5% of the cases my action client waits for the action server, then sends the goal and receives that the goal was rejected.
My node then tries to send the goal again but this is without success.
By now I launch all of the nodes with a 5s delay in between to make sure that every node should have enough time to startup. But still, the error happens every now and then.
I appended the log when it happens down below.
Thanks in advance if anybody has a idea on how to fix this.
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/XXXX-XXXX/.ros/log/2024-11-11-23-10-14-508374-XXXX-precision-99633
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[WARNING] [launch_ros.actions.node]: Parameter file path is not a file: false
[INFO] [ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1]: process started with pid [99634]
[INFO] [rviz2-2]: process started with pid [99636]
[INFO] [ros2-3]: process started with pid [99639]
[INFO] [test_node-4]: process started with pid [99642]
[ros2-3] stdin is not a terminal device. Keyboard handling disabled.[INFO] [1731363015.494682154] [rosbag2_recorder]: Press SPACE for pausing/resuming
[ros2-3] [INFO] [1731363015.496718895] [rosbag2_storage]: Opened database '/home/XXXX-XXXX/rosbag_data/dataset_26/rosbag_12/rosbag_12_0.db3' for READ_WRITE.
[ros2-3] [INFO] [1731363015.498097648] [rosbag2_recorder]: Listening for topics...
[ros2-3] [INFO] [1731363015.498107562] [rosbag2_recorder]: Event publisher thread: Starting
[ros2-3] [INFO] [1731363015.500590848] [rosbag2_recorder]: Subscribed to topic '/rosout'
[ros2-3] [INFO] [1731363015.502583723] [rosbag2_recorder]: Subscribed to topic '/parameter_events'
[ros2-3] [INFO] [1731363015.506261309] [rosbag2_recorder]: Subscribed to topic '/initialpose'
[ros2-3] [INFO] [1731363015.508072367] [rosbag2_recorder]: Subscribed to topic '/goal_pose'
[ros2-3] [INFO] [1731363015.509279878] [rosbag2_recorder]: Subscribed to topic '/events/write_split'
[ros2-3] [INFO] [1731363015.510210838] [rosbag2_recorder]: Subscribed to topic '/clicked_point'
[ros2-3] [INFO] [1731363015.510324476] [rosbag2_recorder]: Recording...
[INFO] [map_server-5]: process started with pid [99722]
[INFO] [lifecycle_manager-6]: process started with pid [99724]
[lifecycle_manager-6] [INFO] [1731363020.530805031] [lifecycle_manager_localization]: Creating
[lifecycle_manager-6] [INFO] [1731363020.535028573] [lifecycle_manager_localization]: Creating and initializing lifecycle service clients
[ros2-3] [INFO] [1731363020.535702418] [rosbag2_recorder]: Subscribed to topic '/diagnostics'
[lifecycle_manager-6] [INFO] [1731363020.540049336] [lifecycle_manager_localization]: Starting managed nodes bringup...
[lifecycle_manager-6] [INFO] [1731363020.540136009] [lifecycle_manager_localization]: Configuring map_server
[map_server-5] [INFO] [1731363020.541253821] [map_server]: 
[map_server-5]  map_server lifecycle node launched. 
[map_server-5]  Waiting on external lifecycle transitions to activate
[map_server-5]  See https://design.ros2.org/articles/node_lifecycle.html for more information.
[map_server-5] [INFO] [1731363020.541432885] [map_server]: Creating
[map_server-5] [INFO] [1731363020.541967609] [map_server]: Configuring
[map_server-5] [INFO] [map_io]: Loading yaml file: /home/XXXX-XXXX/catkin_ws/install/my_gazebo/share/my_gazebo/maps/advanced_maze.yaml
[map_server-5] [DEBUG] [map_io]: resolution: 0.05
[map_server-5] [DEBUG] [map_io]: origin[0]: -20.7984
[map_server-5] [DEBUG] [map_io]: origin[1]: -10.1235
[map_server-5] [DEBUG] [map_io]: origin[2]: 0
[map_server-5] [DEBUG] [map_io]: free_thresh: 0.196
[map_server-5] [DEBUG] [map_io]: occupied_thresh: 0.65
[map_server-5] [DEBUG] [map_io]: mode: trinary
[map_server-5] [DEBUG] [map_io]: negate: 0
[map_server-5] [INFO] [map_io]: Loading image_file: /home/XXXX-XXXX/catkin_ws/install/my_gazebo/share/my_gazebo/maps/advanced_maze.png
[map_server-5] [DEBUG] [map_io]: Read map /home/XXXX-XXXX/catkin_ws/install/my_gazebo/share/my_gazebo/maps/advanced_maze.png: 721 X 402 map @ 0.05 m/cell
[lifecycle_manager-6] [INFO] [1731363020.588377133] [lifecycle_manager_localization]: Activating map_server
[map_server-5] [INFO] [1731363020.588482317] [map_server]: Activating
[map_server-5] [INFO] [1731363020.588882175] [map_server]: Creating bond (map_server) to lifecycle manager.
[ros2-3] [INFO] [1731363020.638351362] [rosbag2_recorder]: Subscribed to topic '/bond'
[ros2-3] [INFO] [1731363020.639805620] [rosbag2_recorder]: Subscribed to topic '/map_server/transition_event'
[ros2-3] [INFO] [1731363020.641178221] [rosbag2_recorder]: Subscribed to topic '/map'
[lifecycle_manager-6] [INFO] [1731363020.691583990] [lifecycle_manager_localization]: Server map_server connected with bond.
[lifecycle_manager-6] [INFO] [1731363020.691631211] [lifecycle_manager_localization]: Managed nodes are active
[lifecycle_manager-6] [INFO] [1731363020.691647370] [lifecycle_manager_localization]: Creating bond timer...
[INFO] [planner_server-7]: process started with pid [99755]
[INFO] [behavior_server-8]: process started with pid [99757]
[INFO] [bt_navigator-9]: process started with pid [99759]
[INFO] [lifecycle_manager-10]: process started with pid [99761]
[lifecycle_manager-10] [INFO] [1731363025.351070231] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: Creating
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
[lifecycle_manager-10] [INFO] [1731363025.358195638] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: Creating and initializing lifecycle service clients
[planner_server-7] [INFO] [1731363025.372977835] [planner_server]: 
[planner_server-7]  planner_server lifecycle node launched. 
[planner_server-7]  Waiting on external lifecycle transitions to activate
[planner_server-7]  See https://design.ros2.org/articles/node_lifecycle.html for more information.
[bt_navigator-9] [INFO] [1731363025.375516906] [bt_navigator]: 
[bt_navigator-9]    bt_navigator lifecycle node launched. 
[bt_navigator-9]    Waiting on external lifecycle transitions to activate
[bt_navigator-9]    See https://design.ros2.org/articles/node_lifecycle.html for more information.
[bt_navigator-9] [INFO] [1731363025.375627038] [bt_navigator]: Creating
[planner_server-7] [INFO] [1731363025.379305078] [planner_server]: Creating
[behavior_server-8] [INFO] [1731363025.384390924] [recoveries_server]: 
[behavior_server-8]     recoveries_server lifecycle node launched. 
[behavior_server-8]     Waiting on external lifecycle transitions to activate
[behavior_server-8]     See https://design.ros2.org/articles/node_lifecycle.html for more information.
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] QStandardPaths: error creating runtime directory '/run/user/1000' (Read-only file system)
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] QStandardPaths: error creating runtime directory '/run/user/1000' (Read-only file system)
[planner_server-7] [INFO] [1731363025.394235199] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: 
[planner_server-7]  global_costmap lifecycle node launched. 
[planner_server-7]  Waiting on external lifecycle transitions to activate
[planner_server-7]  See https://design.ros2.org/articles/node_lifecycle.html for more information.
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] Qt: Session management error: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
[planner_server-7] [INFO] [1731363025.395773304] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Creating Costmap
[ros2-3] [INFO] [1731363025.452102819] [rosbag2_recorder]: Subscribed to topic '/planner_server/transition_event'
[ros2-3] [INFO] [1731363025.452782971] [rosbag2_recorder]: Subscribed to topic '/global_costmap/global_costmap/transition_event'
[ros2-3] [INFO] [1731363025.453435346] [rosbag2_recorder]: Subscribed to topic '/recoveries_server/transition_event'
[lifecycle_manager-10] [INFO] [1731363025.474742961] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: Starting managed nodes bringup...
[lifecycle_manager-10] [INFO] [1731363025.474803219] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: Configuring planner_server
[planner_server-7] [INFO] [1731363025.475074150] [planner_server]: Configuring
[planner_server-7] [INFO] [1731363025.475131876] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Configuring
[planner_server-7] [INFO] [1731363025.480246841] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Using plugin "static_layer"
[planner_server-7] [INFO] [1731363025.486458142] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Subscribing to the map topic (/map) with transient local durability
[planner_server-7] [INFO] [1731363025.487923414] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Initialized plugin "static_layer"
[planner_server-7] [INFO] [1731363025.487976320] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Using plugin "inflation_layer"
[planner_server-7] [INFO] [1731363025.488714473] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Initialized plugin "inflation_layer"
[test_node-4] [INFO] [1731363025.492974897] [test_node]: ---------------------------------------------
[test_node-4] [INFO] [1731363025.493562547] [test_node]: planner
[test_node-4] [INFO] [1731363025.494154333] [test_node]: goal_state:lifecycle_msgs.msg.State(id=10, label='configuring')
[test_node-4] [INFO] [1731363025.494779014] [test_node]: transition:lifecycle_msgs.msg.Transition(id=0, label='')
[test_node-4] [INFO] [1731363025.496123433] [test_node]: ---------------------------------------------
[planner_server-7] [INFO] [1731363025.499500904] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: StaticLayer: Resizing costmap to 721 X 402 at 0.050000 m/pix
[planner_server-7] [INFO] [1731363025.499924340] [planner_server]: Created global planner plugin GridBased of type nav2_navfn_planner/NavfnPlanner
[planner_server-7] [INFO] [1731363025.499979824] [planner_server]: Configuring plugin GridBased of type NavfnPlanner
[planner_server-7] [INFO] [1731363025.500571433] [planner_server]: Planner Server has GridBased  planners available.
[lifecycle_manager-10] [INFO] [1731363025.507828127] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: Configuring bt_navigator
[bt_navigator-9] [INFO] [1731363025.508063530] [bt_navigator]: Configuring
[test_node-4] [INFO] [1731363025.508300086] [test_node]: ---------------------------------------------
[test_node-4] [INFO] [1731363025.508699590] [test_node]: planner
[test_node-4] [INFO] [1731363025.509097498] [test_node]: goal_state:lifecycle_msgs.msg.State(id=2, label='inactive')
[test_node-4] [INFO] [1731363025.509530067] [test_node]: transition:lifecycle_msgs.msg.Transition(id=0, label='')
[test_node-4] [INFO] [1731363025.510005044] [test_node]: ---------------------------------------------
[ros2-3] [WARN] [1731363025.554383793] [ROSBAG2_TRANSPORT]: Hidden topics are not recorded. Enable them with --include-hidden-topics
[ros2-3] [INFO] [1731363025.558742751] [rosbag2_recorder]: Subscribed to topic '/global_costmap/costmap_updates'
[ros2-3] [INFO] [1731363025.560947327] [rosbag2_recorder]: Subscribed to topic '/global_costmap/costmap_raw'
[lifecycle_manager-10] [INFO] [1731363025.560953612] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: Configuring recoveries_server
[behavior_server-8] [INFO] [1731363025.561235176] [recoveries_server]: Configuring
[ros2-3] [INFO] [1731363025.562315937] [rosbag2_recorder]: Subscribed to topic '/global_costmap/costmap'
[ros2-3] [INFO] [1731363025.563756374] [rosbag2_recorder]: Subscribed to topic '/global_costmap/published_footprint'
[ros2-3] [INFO] [1731363025.566570592] [rosbag2_recorder]: Subscribed to topic '/plan'
[behavior_server-8] [INFO] [1731363025.571842787] [recoveries_server]: Creating behavior plugin spin of type nav2_behaviors/Spin
[behavior_server-8] [INFO] [1731363025.572905294] [recoveries_server]: Configuring spin
[behavior_server-8] [INFO] [1731363025.578463478] [recoveries_server]: Creating behavior plugin backup of type nav2_behaviors/BackUp
[behavior_server-8] [INFO] [1731363025.579716724] [recoveries_server]: Configuring backup
[behavior_server-8] [INFO] [1731363025.585448381] [recoveries_server]: Creating behavior plugin drive_on_heading of type nav2_behaviors/DriveOnHeading
[behavior_server-8] [INFO] [1731363025.586886552] [recoveries_server]: Configuring drive_on_heading
[behavior_server-8] [INFO] [1731363025.591947668] [recoveries_server]: Creating behavior plugin wait of type nav2_behaviors/Wait
[behavior_server-8] [INFO] [1731363025.593126464] [recoveries_server]: Configuring wait
[ros2-3] [INFO] [1731363025.672893123] [rosbag2_recorder]: Subscribed to topic '/cmd_vel'
[behavior_server-8] [WARN] [1731363025.696608911] [recoveries_server.rclcpp]: failed to send response to /recoveries_server/change_state (timeout): client will not receive response, at ./src/rmw_response.cpp:154, at ./src/rcl/service.c:314
[ros2-3] [INFO] [1731363028.068678018] [rosbag2_recorder]: Subscribed to topic '/bt_navigator/transition_event'
[INFO] [static_transform_publisher-11]: process started with pid [99825]
[static_transform_publisher-11] [WARN] [1731363030.104538845] []: Old-style arguments are deprecated; see --help for new-style arguments
[static_transform_publisher-11] [INFO] [1731363030.133657880] [static_transform_publisher_JElx68f4UZKE1vhD]: Spinning until stopped - publishing transform
[static_transform_publisher-11] translation: ('3.101575', '7.176479', '0.000000')
[static_transform_publisher-11] rotation: ('-0.690008', '0.000000', '0.000000', '0.723802')
[static_transform_publisher-11] from 'map' to 'base_link'
[ros2-3] [INFO] [1731363030.141605605] [rosbag2_recorder]: Subscribed to topic '/tf_static'
[INFO] [send_new_goal_node-12]: process started with pid [99839]
[send_new_goal_node-12] [INFO] [1731363035.935647532] [send_new_goal_node]: Waiting for action server...
[send_new_goal_node-12] [INFO] [1731363035.936359272] [send_new_goal_node]: Sending goal request...
[send_new_goal_node-12] [INFO] [1731363036.553263653] [send_new_goal_node]: Goal rejected :(

